# How can I make a spreadsheet in tkinter by using entry widgets?

Tags: tkinter, data-entry

I am making an app in which the user will be able to change values in a database by using a spreadsheet made in tkinter, however I am quite lost as to how I can do this. I created the entry boxes with a while loop like this:

```
 while o<numberofstudents:
                global eTrial
                eTrial = Entry(rootOC,width=3)
                eTrial.place(x=200+y*43, y=50 + 25 * o)
                eTrial.delete(0, "end")
                eTrial.insert(0, "100")
                o=o+1
```

How can I get the data from each of these individual entry boxes created with the for loop.
I tried .get() but it doesn't seem to work

Is there a more efficient way to do this, or a solution at least?

Answer (score 1):

`eTrial` only points to the last `Entry` that has been created. There are many ways to do it depending on what you want to do.  Below I've made `eTrial` a list and added a `Button` to print the current content of the list to the terminal.

```
import tkinter as tk

o = 0
numberofstudents = 5
columns = 3

rootOC = tk.Tk()

frame = tk.Frame( rootOC )
frame.grid()
widgets = []
for r in range( 1, 1+numberofstudents ):
    wid_row = []
    for col in range( columns ):
        obj = tk.Entry( frame,width=3 )
        obj.grid( row = r, column = col )
        obj.delete(0, "end")
        obj.insert(0, str( 100*r+col ))
        wid_row.append( obj )
    widgets.append( wid_row )

def onclick():
    for row in widgets:
        for item in row:
            print( item.get(), end = '  ' )
        print()

tk.Button( rootOC, text = 'Print input', command = onclick ).grid()

rootOC.mainloop()
```

If I click 'Print Input' immediately after the GUI opens I get:

```
100  101  102  
200  201  202  
300  301  302  
400  401  402  
500  501  502
```

Comment: How can I update the contents of this list through the entry boxes? I want to edit the entry boxes, get the new value inserted to them and then save them in a database.

Comment: If you update the entry widget contents and click 'Print input' afterwards the new contents will be printed.  You'll need to amend `onclick` ( or whatever you call it) to extract the data, using get, and then write them to a database rather than print them to the screen.  The list is a list of `tk.Entries`, the widgets themselves, not a list of the strings entered into them.  That's why `ent.get` is called in the loop to extract the text that's been entered in each `Entry`.

Comment: Yeah I adjusted onclick to be that way however, It only saves the data from the last column of the entry widgets. The thing I am trying to create is an excel spreadsheet like structure and thus 2 dimensional. It seems this only works 1 dimensionally, how can I make sure it saves the data of the other columns?

Comment: You need to ensure you keep references to each entry in the spreadsheet.  I've shown this in a list of lists.  I've amended the answer to do 3 columns using a for loop and the grid geometry manager to avoid the place arithmetic.